# ViewdidAppear fires for the second VC before the first

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
2015-02-06 23:23:35.976 a[47551:2124298] second view did load
2015-02-06 23:23:35.978 a[47551:2124298] first view did load
2015-02-06 23:23:36.060 a[47551:2124298] second view did appear
2015-02-06 23:23:36.062 a[47551:2124298] first view did appear
```

The above describes my problem. I want to do stuff only after the second view appears, but all the events first as soon as I launch the app.

The first view:

```
@interface AddViewController ()

@end

@implementation AddViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"first view did load");
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    NSLog(@"first view did appear");
}

- (IBAction)addBtnPressed:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"add Btn pressed");
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}


#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    ViewController *destVC = [segue destinationViewController];
    destVC.destStation = self.destField.text;
}
```

The second view:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

NSLog(@"second view did load");

manager = [[ CLLocationManager alloc] init];
geocoder = [[ CLGeocoder alloc] init];

[manager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
```

//    [manager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
}

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    NSLog(@"second view did appear");

    manager.delegate = self;
    manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

    NSLog(@"setting destStation %@", self.destStation);
    self.destField.text = self.destStation;
    self.destStationLoc = [LocationCalc findDestStationLoc:self.destStation stationInfos:[StationDB database].stationInfos];
}
```

The segue is connected from the button from the first VC.
**Am I doing something wrong?**

Comment: Did you click on that button ? which connected to segue ?

Comment: yes but all the logs were printed even before I clicked the button.

Comment: I guess, somewhere in your code you are doing something which is forcing the second view to load in the memory. Put a debug-breakpoint in the viewDidLoad of Second-view. Run the app, when break-point reaches there, trace the thread to find the line-of-code causing the view to load.